# Could not find dcciosarm64270.dll

Tags: delphi

I installed Delphi 10.4 Community Edition and Delphi iOS Community Platform, but when I compile my project, I get an error:

> Could not find dcciosarm64270.dll

I could compile this project with Delphi 10.3 Community Edition, and I can find `dcciosarm64260.dll` in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\bin` folder.

But I cannot find `dcciosarm64270.dll` in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin` folder.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Do you have selected IOS 64bit platform when installing? Run setup again.

Comment: Sorry I mistook to write.
I can find dcciosarm64260.dll in 10.3 folder.
I cannot find dcciosarm64270.dll in 10.4 folder.

Comment: Please read http://delphicodemonkey.blogspot.com/2020/10/a-few-quick-tips-about-downloading.html

Comment: I installed Delphi 10.4.2 Community Edition Patch 1.0 from GetIt and the problem has been resolved.  Thank you very much all.

Comment: @kiiroitori you should consider [moving that into an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) instead.